# Kohana 3.3 ORM _has_many _belongs_to

Tags: orm, kohana-3, kohana-orm

I am trying to set up a product object in Kohana 3.3 using the built in ORM.  I want it so that when I call:

```
    $p1 = ORM::factory('product')
        ->where('product_type', '=', '1')
        ->find_all();
```

it will create an object of this structure:

```
Model_Product Object
(
    [_long_list_of_kohana_properties] => Array ()
    [_object:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [product_type] => 1
            ...
            [product_attributes] => Array (List of attributes)
        )
)
```

Currently, it produces this:

```
Model_Product Object
(
    [_long_list_of_kohana_properties] => Array ()
    [_object:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [product_type] => 1
            ...
        )
)
```

This is the relevant code for the objects and the _has_many / _belongs_to :

```
class Model_Product extends ORM
{
    protected $_db = 'default';
    protected $_table_name  = 'product';
    protected $_primary_key = 'id';

    protected $_table_columns = array(
        'id',
        'product_type',
        ...
    );

    protected $_has_many = array(
        'product_attributes'    => array(
            'model' => 'productAttributes',
            'foreign_key' => 'product_id',
            'far_key' => 'id',
        )
    );
}

class Model_ProductAttribute extends ORM
{
    protected $_db = 'default';
    protected $_table_name  = 'productAttributes';
    protected $_primary_key = 'id';

    protected $_table_columns = array(
        'id',
        'product_id',
        'attribute_name',
        'attribute_value',
    );

    protected $_belongs_to = array('product' => array(
            'model' => 'product',
            'foreign_key' => 'product_id',
            'far_key' => 'product_id',
        )
    );
}
```

I can't seem to get the right combination of foreign_key and far_key values to make this work...  Also, I can't find a good explanation of the purpose of "far_key". If someone can explain foreign vs far that might solve this problem, ha.

Any suggestions as to where I might be messing up?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`Foreign key` is the key on `this` object. That contains the data about the relationship.

`Far key` is the key on the `other` object. That contains the data about the relationship. That key is 'far away'

In a `has_many` relationship, the other objects 'belong to' this object. Those objects have a key on it which refers to `this`. Thus the `far key` should be `'product_id'` and the foreign key has no influence on this relationship. As there is no (and can't be) a key on `this` object that points to thousands of attribute objects. Thus:

```
class Model_Product extends ORM {

    protected $_has_many = array(
        'product_attributes'    => array(
        'model' => 'productAttributes',
        'far_key' => 'product_id',
    ));
}
```

In a `belongs_to` relationship. `this` object has a key on it which points to it's `parent` (or whatever). Thus the local key (`foreign_key`) should be `product_id` and the `far_key` has no influence on this relationship. As there is no (and can't be) a key on the other object that points to all it's children. Thus:

```
class Model_ProductAttribute extends ORM {

    protected $_belongs_to = array('product' => array(
        'model' => 'product',
        'foreign_key' => 'product_id',
        'far_key' => 'product_id',
    ));
}
```

I hope this answered your question. Took me a while to figure it out as well.