# How to join tables using ORM in Kohana

Tags: php, mysql, orm, kohana

Im as u can see in my history kinda new into kohana, but learning quick.. I am struggling on a weird problem that worked before in Kohana 3.3

I want to create a join query between two databases. i created the Model_Veiligen en Model_Veilingvoorkeur models, and put this as ORM call:

This is the RIGHT JOIN QUERY:

```
 SELECT `vastprijs`, `veilingen`.`id` AS `id`, `veilingen`.`gid` AS `gid`, `veilingen`.`provincie` AS `provincie`, `veilingen`.`created` AS `created`, `veilingen`.`termtime` AS `termtime`, `veilingen`.`postcode` AS `postcode`, `veilingen`.`lat` AS `lat`, `veilingen`.`lng` AS `lng`, `veilingen`.`titel` AS `titel`, `veilingen`.`beschrijving` AS `beschrijving`, `veilingen`.`images` AS `images`, `veilingen`.`ip` AS `ip`, `veilingen`.`unique` AS `unique` FROM `veilingen` AS `veilingen` RIGHT JOIN `veilingvoorkeur` ON (`veilingen`.`id` = `vid`) ORDER BY `veilingen`.`created` DESC LIMIT 10
```

DIT IS DE LEFT:

```
SELECT `vastprijs`, `veilingen`.`id` AS `id`, `veilingen`.`gid` AS `gid`,     `veilingen`.`provincie` AS `provincie`, `veilingen`.`created` AS `created`,     `veilingen`.`termtime` AS `termtime`, `veilingen`.`postcode` AS `postcode`,     `veilingen`.`lat` AS `lat`, `veilingen`.`lng` AS `lng`, `veilingen`.`titel` AS `titel`,     `veilingen`.`beschrijving` AS `beschrijving`, `veilingen`.`images` AS `images`,     `veilingen`.`ip` AS `ip`, `veilingen`.`unique` AS `unique` FROM `veilingen` AS `veilingen`     LEFT JOIN `veilingvoorkeur` ON (`veilingen`.`id` = `vid`) ORDER BY `veilingen`.`created` DESC LIMIT 10
```

RIGHT JOIN output:

```
[_object:protected] => Array ( [id] => [gid] => [provincie] => [created] => [termtime] => [postcode] => [lat] => [lng] => [titel] => [beschrijving] => [images] => [ip] => [unique] => [vastprijs] => 56 )
```

LEFT JOIN OUTPUT:

```
[_object:protected] => Array ( [id] => 121 [gid] => 10 [provincie] => 9 [created] => 1385534362 [termtime] => 1386743962 [postcode] => 8031CJ [lat] => 52.528510 [lng] => 6.081043 [titel] => gdfgd [beschrijving] => fgfdgdfgfdsfsfd [images] => [{"file_name":"5a5a7a7ef44.png","file_size":238687,"file_type":"image\/png","file_link":"uploads\/\/5a5a7a7ef44.png"}] [ip] => 94.215.33.178 [unique] => [vastprijs] => )
```

My code for the Left or right join is as follows:

```
$veiling = ORM::factory('veilingen')
        ->select('vastprijs')
        ->join('veilingvoorkeur', 'RIGHT')
        ->on('veilingen.id', '=', 'vid')
        ->order_by('veilingen.created', DESC)
        ->limit(10)
        ->find_all();
```

The problem im hanging into is that i don't understand the has_many and belongs_to, the example above worked before, but not anymore.

The problem that occurs if i change RIGHT in LEFT, it will output all data from the veilingen table. But it ignores the data of the vastprijs field. But if i print the foreach element, i can see that the vastprijs has been selected. Except for data.

If i use RIGHT, instead of left. above story occurs but then otherwise. vastprijs isn't empty and veilingen fields are empty. but shown.

---

My main question is, how can i relate those 2 tables together with maybe has_many, but veilingen only has_one veilingvoorkeur. The key is veilingen.id = veilingvoorkeur.vid

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Why aren't you using a `has_many`/`belongs_to` (1:n) relationship?

Comment: i just added some more information, i forgot about the question. Thanks in advance. Maybe you can explain me how to build the relationship between the Models?

Comment: Does `veilingvoorkeur` always have a related item in `veilingen` (or can `vid` be empty)?

Comment: Kingkero, vid can never be empty, every veilingen entry id has a veilingvoorkeur entry on vid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My main question is, how can i relate those 2 tables together with maybe has_many, but veilingen only has_one veilingvoorkeur. The key is veilingen.id = veilingvoorkeur.vid

Problem where? Kohana also offers the possibility of [`has_one`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/orm/relationships#hasone):

```
class Model_veilingen extends ORM {

    protected $_has_one = array(
        'veilingvoorkeur' => array(
            'model' => 'veilingvoorkeur',
            'far_key' => 'vid',
        ),
    );

}
```

Now as relationships have always two sides, you need to define the other as well. [`belongs_to`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/orm/relationships#belongsto) is used when there always needs to be something on the other side.

```
class Model_veilingvoorkeur extends ORM {

    protected $_belongs_to = array(
        'veilingen' => array(
            'model' => 'veilingen',
            'foreign_key' => 'vid',
        ),
    );

}
```

If you are unsure whether to use `foreign_key` or `far_key`, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18250207/1557526) should help you. Also to explain relationships a little more:

- A `has_one` B: One item from A has either one or no item from B related
- A `belongs_to` B: One item from A **always** has one item from B related

---

Your query could now be done like this:

```
$veilings = ORM::factory('veilingen')->order_by('created', DESC')->limit(10)
    ->find_all();
foreach ($veilings as $veiling) {
    $veiling->veilingvoorkeur->find();
    print $veiling->veilingvoorkeur->vastprijs;
}
```

I'm honestly not quite sure what to do if `$veiling` as no related `veilingvoorkeur`, but it should be possible to do like this (from the idea)

```
    $veilingvoorkeur = $veiling->veilingvoorkeur->find();
    if (!empty($veilingvoorkeur))
        print $veilingvoorkeur->vastprijs;
```

---

I didn't test the code, if it fails somewhere I hope to at least have clarified on how to solve this using relationships.

Comment: Foreign key is the key that referates to the cother table its matching id ? @kingkero

Comment: Correct (just as in SQL)

Comment: Database_Exception [ 1054 ]: Unknown column 'veilingvoorkeur.veilingen_id' in 'where clause' [ SELECT `veilingvoorkeur`.`id` AS `id`, `veilingvoorkeur`.`vid` AS `vid`, `veilingvoorkeur`.`startbod` AS `startbod`, `veilingvoorkeur`.`opbod` AS `opbod`, `veilingvoorkeur`.`vastprijs` AS `vastprijs` FROM `veilingvoorkeur` AS `veilingvoorkeur` WHERE `veilingvoorkeur`.`veilingen_id` = '124' LIMIT 1 ]

It 's not really looking like a join query and i get a strange error ... he's trying to load veilingvoorkeur.veilingen_id @kingkero

Comment: Did you define the Models properly? What I posted is just an outline of the relationship itself

Comment: i guess so, i inserted the protected has_one and belongs_to into my models, and after that he gave me that error.

Comment: Sorry, gotta got offline now. Check out the documentation on relationships and play a little around, this should (in theory) be simple

Comment: i finally got it working. I don't know exactly what i changed. but your answer is clear to understand how to work with orm.. i tried btw to add a third table, but its not possible because you cannot redeclare has_one, now i used has_many, so i can join a 3rd table.. is this the usual way ? or should i do it on an other way? @kingkero

Comment: You can add other relationships by extending the array (not redeclaring it). `$_has_one = array( 'veilingen'=>array(...), 'another'=>array(..), );`