# Kohana - ORM_Tree

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3.3

Found a couple of links suggesting using 'ORM_Tree' to handle a self-referential table:

- http://ninjapenguin.co.uk/blog/2008/09/25/kohana-orm-tip-orm-tree
- http://attic.ist.unomaha.edu/blogs/zac/2009/12/15/orm-tree-in-kohana/

However, get an error from the controller saying 'Class ORM_Tree' not found.
My model is as follows:

```
class Model_Article extends ORM_Tree {
    protected $children = "categories";
}
```

I am utilizing version 3.3.1 with the following in the controller:

```
class Controller_Category extends Controller{

    //View
    public function action_index(){
        $categories = ORM::factory('Category')->find_all();
        $view = new View('category/index');
        $view->set('category', $categories);
        $this->response->body($view);
    }
}
```

Was the class removed from version 3.3.1?
If so, does anyone have suggestions for handling a self-referential table as shown below:

> category_id - int(11) - No
>   category_name - varchar(45) - No
>   category_description - varchar(250) - Yes - NULL
>   __parent_id - int(11) - Yes - NULL

Hopefully, I got that table clear enough to understand.  The __parent_id has a foreign-key relationship to the category_id.  The __parent_id can be null (to allow for a root or even several top-level).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I had very high hopes to utilize the tree in a project.  Please forgive if this has been answered elsewhere (please understand that I did not ask until I had 'googled' and even 'yahooed').

I am extremely new to Kahona as this framework seemed to be the best fit. I had examined somewhat Cakephp but did not care for their handling of AuthAcl - seemed a bit convoluted in that you had a 'tree' with a right and left node which I felt was unnecessarily complex.  However, I have as yet not gotten to the AuthAcl of Kahona and may find that such an implementation is necessary.

Comment: They do have a kohana tag, I just added it. You might try looking in an older version of the source for the class.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for such a construct as you can easily design a self referencing ORM class. I'm not sure what you want, as the class is called `Model_Article` but the table  has `category_*` columns.

So I will assume that you have a table `categories` with the given columns. Now a Model for this could look like this

```
class Model_Category extends ORM {
    protected $_table_name = "categories",
        $_has_many = array(
            'children' => array(
                'model' => 'Category',
                'far_key' => '__parent_id'
            )
        ),
        $_has_one = array(
            'parent' => array(
                'model' => 'Category',
                'foreign_key' => '__parent_id'
            )
        );
}
```

This is not tested but should at least give you the idea of the implementation. You can always read in the [documentation](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/orm/relationships) or the [API browser](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/ORM) on how to use what. Also I would suggest playing around a bit with various settings if you feel unsatisfied.

If you wonder about whether to use `far_key` or `foreign_key`, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18250207/1557526) should help.

Comment: This looks promising and I will most certainly give this a shot and get back to you.  This is my first post on this site and hardly expected two replies within 20-min.

Comment: You're welcome! I currently don't have a running Kohana environment, so if it doesn't work on the first try, try it with changing `foreign_key`/`far_key` and `__parent_id`/`category_id`